# Replacing multiple charcters in one field with one query

Tags: sql, ms-access-2010

I have a field that has data with the following formats:

45
<45
[45]
.45

I want to replace "[", "]", and "<" with a "space", but keep "."

It is easy to replace the square brackets with:

**UPDATE Table SET Table.Field = Replace(Replace(Field,'[',''),']','');**

and the less than sign with:

**UPDATE Table SET Table.Field = Replace(Field,'<','');**

However, I don't know how to accomplish this with one query. My SQL is limited but I am sure there is a way.

Comment: You're already replacing both brackets in a single statement. Could you not extrapolate that out to taking care of the '<' as well?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use nested functions:

```
UPDATE Table
    SET Table.Field = Replace(Replace(Replace(Field, '[', ''), ']', ''), '<', '')
```